# Android TV Fragment (Main Fragment) Coming in Vertical Orientation?

Tags: java, android, fragment, leanback

After Running the code my screen coming in Vertical orientation, why??

## This is my main fragment(XML)----

i want in everything in landscape mode as it Usually display on TV..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="com.amriksingpadam.my_androidtv.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

I am not able to find the answer please help??

## Main fragment (Java)--

```
public class MainFragment extends BrowseFragment {
    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.i(TAG,"On Activity Created!!");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setupUIElements();
    }

    public void setupUIElements(){
        setTitle("BOB TV");
    }

}
```

Comment: In your manifest file, set activity orientation as landscape

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com......">

    <uses-permission .... />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="..."
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/banner" . <--- You need this
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"> . <--- You need this

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/banner" <--- You need this
            android:icon="@drawable/banner"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/banner"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> <--- You need this
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/> <--- You need this
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```